# pushViewController : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I have developed a application for iPhone, I want to continue this application in iPad, The interface of iPad is not the same with iPhone, and I am developing the interface for the iPad, and I have a question for passing uiviewcontroller to another uiviewcontroller.

I detect the device in function `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` like this

```
if( (modelName == "iPad 2")||(modelName == "iPad 3")||(modelName == "iPad 4")||(modelName == "iPad Air")||(modelName == "iPad Air 2")||(modelName == "iPad Mini")||(modelName == "iPad Mini 2")||(modelName == "iPad Mini 3")||(modelName == "iPad Mini 4")||(modelName == "iPad Pro"))
    {
        ...
    }else
    {
        ...
    }
```

After I create two views(view A and view B) and I embedded two navigation controller to the two views.

In the view A, I add this code to pass view B,

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewBID") as! ViewBViewController

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I did the same thing in iPhone, and it works well, but for iPad, I aways get error like `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I don't know why, I embedded navigation controller in view controller, so I think `self.navigationController` is not null. Do you know how to resolve this problem ? Thank you very much.

PS: I think perhaps I didn't use the right way to separtor the interface iPhone and iPad, but I am not sure for this... I need your help, Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: I'm not a Swift expert myself, but I'm curious as to why you're not using AutoLayout instead of designing different interfaces for different screens? :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: Because the two interfaces are so big big difference

Comment: Please show more code

Answer (score 0):

Try using size classes. You do not have to use your code to detect the device. Using size classes you can have different interfaces for iPads, iPhones in portrait and iPhone in landscape or just for iPhone 6s plus.

Size classes in Xcode less than 8 looks like this[image: here to select them]

and here you select your devices.

[image: and then select device]

I recommend downloading Xcode 8 beta, because they are little bit different in Xcode 8, but same principle.

You can search for some tutorials about size classes in Xcode.

Comment: Or look at apple developer: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html